# Entity custom navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm trying to work out how to add a navigation property to the principal entity in this scenario - (maybe it's not possible with the dual primary key):

```
public class EntityA
{
    [Key]
    public int EntityAPrimaryKey1 { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int EntityAPrimaryKey2 { get; set; }

    //What goes here?
    public virtual EntityB EntityB { get; set;}
}


public class EntityB
{
    [Key]
    public int EntityBPrimaryKey { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int EntityAPrimaryKey1 { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int EntityBPrimaryKey2 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EntityAPrimaryKey1,EntityAPrimaryKey2")]
    public virtual EntityA EntityA { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since EF can't tell by the name, you can add this annotation.

```
[ForeignKey("EntityBPrimaryKey ")]
public virtual EntityB EntityB { get; set;}
```

You can also set it up with a fluent configuration.